# How to put animation effects on C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, animation

I am using wpf application where i am using an image. I want to put some animation effects on it. When a user clicks on button it dissapear from the screen and move away from left to right or some this kind of animation.
What classes do i need to use.
Can I use silverlight or flash or something else here

Comment: No, but animations are not Silverlight only. Can you explain a little more what you want to do?

Comment: i want to Flip the image from left to right

Comment: Perhaps you should be a little more specific to what you are asking.. do you want a tuturial for animations for WPF? Or Flash? What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

```
DoubleAnimation TopAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
TopAnimation.From = YourImage.Top;
TopAnimation.To = WhereYouWantItToEndUp
TopAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(AnDuration);

YourImage.BeginAnimation(YourImage.TopProperty, TopAnimation);
```

And you can chain a bunch of them together and they will all happen at the same time.

You can also do it in xaml

If you want to know when its completed add a listener to the completed event of the animation

Comment: DoubleAnimation TopAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            TopAnimation.From = 1.0;
            TopAnimation.To = 0.0;
            TopAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            TopAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
            TopAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;


            imgLeft1.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Controls.Image.TopProperty , TopAnimation);

it will give error at TopProperty